# custom floats addition, implementing math expression - C

Tags: c, floating-point, addition, bit

I'm implementing a new kind of float "NewFloat" in C, it uses 32bits, it has **no sign bit** (only positive numbers.
So the whole 32bits are used by the exponent or mantissa.

In my example, I have 6bits for the exponent (**EXPBITS**) and 26 for the mantissa (**MANBITS**).
And We have an offset which is used for representing negative exponents, which is (**2^(EXPBITS-1)-1**).

Given a NewFloat nf1, the translation to a real number is done like this:
nf1 = 2^(exponent - offset) * (1 + mantissa/2^MANBITS).

Now, given two NewFloats (nf1, nf2), each with it's (exp1, man1, exp2, man2 and the same offset),
**Assuming that nf1 > nf2**, I can calculate the exponent and mantissa of the sum of both nf1 and nf2, and this is done like this: [link](https://d1b10bmlvqabco.cloudfront.net/attach/hqaz5afvfmt7os/hmadnjouv0c91/i44qg1g91c0i/sum.eps)

To spare your time, I found that:
Exponent of the sum is: exp1
Mantissa of the sum is: man1 + 2^(exp2 - exp1 + MANBITS) + 2^(exp2 - exp1) * man2

To ease with the code, I split to work and calc separately each component of the mantissa:
x = 2^(exp2 - exp1 + MANBITS)
y = 2^(exp2 - exp1) * man2

I'm kind of sure that I'm not implementing right the mantissa part:

```
unsigned long long x = (1 << (exp2 - exp1 + MANBITS));
unsigned long long y = ((1 << exp2) >> exp1) * man2;
unsigned long long tempMan = man1;
tempMan += x + y;

unsigned int exp = exp1;                                    // CAN USE DIRECTLY EXP1.
unsigned int man = (unsigned int)tempMan;
```

The sum is represented like this: 
sum = 2^(exp1 - offset) * (1 + (man1 + x + y)/2^MANBITS).

The last thing I have to handle is the case of an overflow of the sum's mantissa.
In this case, I should add 1 to the exponent and **divide the whole (1 + (man + x + y)2^MANBITS)** expression.

In that case, given that I only need to represent the nominator in bits, how do I do that after the division?

Is there any problem in my implementation? Which I have a feeling there is.

**If you have a better way of doing this, I would be really happy to hear about it.**

**Please, don't ask me why I do this.. it's an exercise which I've been trying to solve for more than 10 hours.**

Comment: Writing a floating point suite is not a trivial task. I have done it when library functions were either unacceptably slow or non-existant. If you have to reinvent the wheel, at least make the format IEEE compliant.

Comment: If you do get this "working", you must test the corner conditions *ad nauseam* as well as supposedly routine tasks. Write a test program that will cycle through perms of valid and invalid data, run it overnight, comparing the results with a well founded implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code is doing `signed int` shifts and certainly `unsigned long long` is desired.

```
// unsigned long long x = (1    << (exp2 - exp1 + MANBITS));
   unsigned long long x = (1LLU << (exp2 - exp1 + MANBITS));
```

Notes:

Suggest more meaningful variable names like `x_mantissa`.

Rounding not implemented.  Rounding can cause a need for increase in exponent.

Overflow not detected/implemented.

Sub-normals not implemented.    Should `NewFloat` not use them, not that `a-b --> 0` does not mean `a == b`.

Comment: Xcode does not know "LUU" but "LLU" and I guess that's what you meant.
Hmm, that did not solve me the problem, nor I understand why it's needed...
As long as I do left shifts, why should I care about the type (signed or unsigned)?

I should use unsigned if I want to push 0's while right shifting, shouldn't I?

Thanks for your comments though.

Comment: @johni Let's assume `int` is 32-bits.  Performing `1 << 48` is shifting an `int` more than its width which is undefined behavior (UB).  A typical result is that only the least significant 5 bits of 48 are used and a result of `1 << 16` occurs.  By using `1LLU`, code is shifting a `unsigned long long` (at least 64-bit type).

Comment: @johni Concerning signed vs. unsigned integers: code is forming a biased mantissa as an unsigned integer result.  Certainly less confusing to others if code uses an unsigned type rather than an signed type to represent the unsigned biased mantissa.

Comment: yeah I understand now why LLU us needed here. thanks.

Still couldn't fix the problems though.

Comment: @johni Posting more info, examples, or failure details would help.

Comment: Apparently I did not take the right action when overflowing and that's the reason for these issues.

Comment: @johni If this answer did not solve some of your issues, suggest posting your own solution and accepting it to complete this post.